# How to remove white border box around an image in mobile view?

Tags: blogger

In my blogger posts I have uploaded some images and by using CSS codes, I have removed white box border formed around  images in desktop version. But I am unable to remove this white box border formed around the image in mobile version. Suggest any suitable solutions.

Comment: Please post your CSS code for the desktop version and show what happens with it on mobile. Please also post any other code you think may be relevant (i.e. the rest of the HTML and CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you may need to set your Mobile Template to "Custom"

Then go to Theme > Customize > Advanced > Add CSS > then add below...

```css
.post-body img, 
.post-body .tr-caption-container {
  border:0!important;
}
```

Click Apply to Blog > Preview your changes.